# nginx redirect (or proxy) to another app on localhost

Tags: nginx, proxy

I want to use nginx to redirect (or proxy) request from 7443 to 8443.

```
https://serverIP:7443/oldApp/  ==> https://serverIP:8443/new/app/
```

I've tried some of settings, but still got 404 or empty page.

Here are my nginx config:

```
//ssl settings ..

server {
     listen [::]:7443 ipv6only=off ssl;
     server_name  localhost;
     location /oldApp/ {    
          proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding        "";
          proxy_set_header  Host                    $host;
          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
          #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       8443;
          #add_header       Front-End-Https        on;

          proxy_pass      https://127.0.0.1:8443/new/app;
     }}
```

And here are some assumptions that might be helpful for directive usage:

1. for different port/scheme => use proxy_pass (or proxy_redirect)
2. for different virtual host/subdomain/folder => use sub_filter (or rewrite?)

Are those assumptions correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not working — is not a problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this as below:

```
server {
    listen [::]:7443 ipv6only=off ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    location ^~ /oldApp {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/new/app/;

        # Here is the trick: add the port behind $host
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host:8443;

        # This make sure your session won't lose  
        proxy_cookie_path   ~*^/.* /;

    }}
```

Many thanks